# Rails using variable name as key for json array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In Rails I'm rendering a json array, but I need one of the keys to have a variable name depending on the params. something like this:

```
render json: {
        key1: values,
        params[:type]: more_values,
        labels: some_lables
      }
```

obviously this doesn't work, but what will?

Comment: you miss a comma after `key1: values`

Comment: fixed it, unfortunate typo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use *interpolation* :

```
render json: {
        :key1 => values,
        :"#{params[:type]}" => more_values,
        labels: some_lables
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a hash and render it as JSON.

```
h = { key1: values, labels: some_labels }
h[params[:type]] = more_values
render json: h.to_json
```

Comment: They are both essentially the same thing, but whatever works for you is perfectly fine.